# How to get indices of multiple item that were selected in listbox

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox

I want to get indices of all the items that are selected in given listbox, there is a `SelectedItems` method which return a collection of items:

```
listbox.SelectedItems
```

But there is no `SelectedIndices` method. The collection also doesn't contain an index for each item.

How can I know which item was selected in my listbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `IndexOf` to find their index in the collection of items. For example, when binding a collection of items:

```
// create your list of items to display
List<MyObject> items = new List<MyObject>();

// NOTE: populate your list here!

// bind the items
listBox.ItemsSource = items;
```

You can find the selected index as follows:

```
var selectedItem = (MyObject)listBox.SelectedItems[0]
int index = items.IndexOf(selectedItem);
```

Comment: And what if the same element ocurs on the list twice?

Comment: IndefOf doesn't work if 'MyObject' is string and you have duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

If you're binding a `List` or an `ObservableCollection` of items to the `ListBox` use

```
var indices = new List<Int32>();
foreach( var item in listbox.SelectedItems ) {
  var index = boundList.IndexOf( item as MyDataType );

  if( index != -1 ) {
    indices.Add( index );
  }
}
```